# Не запускается приложение в Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

Не запускается приложение которое было собрано под линукс центос 7. Я пытаюсь его запустить на Убунте. Ранее не запускал на убунте его. Выдает следующую ошибку.

```
root@alexqa-vir:/home/alexqa/Downloads/build# ./nmos-cpp-registry 
./nmos-cpp-registry: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.10: no version information available (required by ./nmos-cpp-registry)
./nmos-cpp-registry: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.10: no version information available (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.10)
./nmos-cpp-registry: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.10: no version information available (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.10)
./nmos-cpp-registry: relocation error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.10: symbol __libc_enable_secure, version GLIBC_2.2.5 not defined in file ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 with link time reference
root@alexqa-vir:/home/alexqa/Downloads/build#
```

Подскажите как исправить. Уже сбился со счета попыток (

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
```

Попробуй